# comma separated cck multivalues in a view

Tags: views, entities

I've created a cck field and called it authors so the machine name is field_authors. To print this field in a view template, i'm doing this - `print $fields['field_authors_value']->content;`
In case is there 2 or 3 values it prints each value on separate line, and i want something like author1, author2, author3. (comma separated)

Tried to do this way in template.php:

```
function mytheme_content_view_multiple_field($items, $field, $values) {
  $output = '';
  switch($field['field_name']) {
    case 'field_authors_value':
      $output .= '<div class="field-item">'. implode(', ', $items) .'</div>';
      break;

    default:
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (!empty($item) || $item == '0') {
      $output .= '<div class="field-item">'. $item .'</div>';
    }
      }
      break;
  }
  return $output;
}
```

but it has no effect. What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the following on drupal.org:
http://drupal.org/node/1018198#comment-3993646

> You can do this by copying "views-view-field.tpl.php" into your theme's directory, under 
>   a name the view will recognize it selectively. Put the following code in it:
>
> > `print preg_replace('/<\/div><div[^>]+>/i', ', ', $output);`

In your case, I think it would be:

> views-view-field--VIEWNAME--field_authors_value.tpl.php

Comment: Thanks that worked. But it is possible to do that a more Drupl way? :)